# How to compare strings in PyQt5 in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to make a GUI app usin `PyQt5`, where if you click a button then some random text will appear in the label. If that random text will be equal to *Whats up?* then it will type `True` in the terminal. Else, it will print `False`.

However I am getting `False` every time...

**Here is my code:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel
import sys
import random

lis = ["Hello world", "Hey man", "Yo buddy", "Go to hell", "Whats up?"]

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.setGeometry(200,200,300,300) 
        self.setWindowTitle("WhatsApp Sheduled")

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("My first label")
        self.label.move(120, 120)

        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.b1.setText("Click here")
        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.clicked)

    def clicked(self):
        self.label.setText(random.choice(lis))
        if self.label == "Whats up?":
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")

def clicked():
    print("Clicked!")

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()  # It's important to call this function
```

**Any help would be appreciated...**

Please just tell me how to do that. I am new to GUI, so didn't know much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply forgot to use its `text` accessor function :

```
    if self.label.text() == "Whats up?":
```

(notice that it is a function, hence the parentheses after text).

[edit] To answer your second question:

```
def initUI(self):
#...
        self.label2 = QLabel(self)
        self.label2.setText("Guido")
        self.label2.move(0, 120)
        self.label2.setVisible(False)

    def clicked(self):
        self.label.setText(random.choice(lis))
        if self.label.text() == "Whats up?":
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")
        self.label2.setVisible( self.label.text() == "Whats up?" )
```

Comment: What if I want that if condition is true then except printing true on terminal, it will show a label on GUI else it will remain hidden? How to do that? @Demi-Lune

Comment: You could play with its `visible` attribute: for instance, to only show it when it contains WhatsUp, you could: `self.label.setVisible( self.label.text() == "Whats up?" ) `

Comment: But maybe you meant "another label remains hidden", in which case you would do the same with `self.label2` (create it in initUi, then set it [in]visible as you like).